# Should all tables be related in a Database or Is it ok to leave some of them?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

Often we come across some small insignificant (debatable) tables left out as stand alone. Although they are used in joins (sparingly) but still developers don't bother to relate them.

May be too many References made the inserts slow.

This leads to this question : 
**As a thumb rule should we relate all the tables in the database ? If no then where to draw the line?**

thanks

Comment: I would say that unless there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever,  then you should relate the tables and impose referential integrity. The exception would be a performance problem.

Comment: @Tarik Does that mean design all tables with referential integrity and remove references when performance is hit ?

Comment: Well, that would rather be an exception to be justified by a significant performance issue that cannot be resolved otherwise.

Comment: I would add foreign keys where data is related. leaving out these relation (foreign key constraints) may lead to corrupt data, I would rather have a bit slower query then having corrupt data in my database.

Comment: My two cents: if data integrity doesn't matter, why does speed matter? Getting the wrong answer fast is a questionable goal.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Great Argument. +1 to that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign Keys are not always a negative impact to performance, they can be a positive impact as well.  Database relationships do more than just ensure referential integrity, they also help teach SQL Server about the nature of your data.  The fact that two fields are related can give clues as to the cardinality of your queries and thus the optimizer actually takes these relationships into consideration when it's estimating the cost of your query.

In my opinion, if two fields are related in your database, they should have a defined relationship.  In general, the more you can teach SQL Server about your data (not just relationships, but CHECK constraints as well), the better it will be at generating efficient query plans.  Of course like anything in SQL Server, there are exceptions to the rule, but if you want a rule of thumb, I would lean toward defining all the relationships.

Comment: Yeah you can always speed up performance problems by identifying the bottleneck. Data corruption is not a genie you want to let out of the bottle.